# Efficient way to handle big data in R

Tags: r, bigdata

I have a huge csv-file, 1.37 GB, and when running my glm in R, it crashes because I do not have enough memory allocated. You know, the regular error..

Are there no alternative to packages ff and bigmemory, because they do not seem to work well for me, because my columns are a mix of integer and characters, and it seems with the two packages I have to specify what type my columns are, either char or integer.

We are soon in 2018 and about to put people on Mars; are there no simple "read.csv.xxl" function we can use?

Comment: You don't have 2GB of memory on you computer? Maybe time to upgrade.

Comment: I have 8 GB, but the glm-calculation crashes.

Comment: did any of the pointers in http://www.bnosac.be/index.php/blog/10-bigglm-on-your-big-data-set-in-open-source-r-it-just-works-similar-as-in-sas work?

Comment: I did not know of that, so I have not tried that. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

I would first address your question by recognizing that just because your sample data takes 1.37 GB does *not* at all mean that 1.37 GB would be satisfactory to do all your calculations using the `glm` package.  Most likely, one of your calculations could spike at at least a multiple of 1.37 GB.

For the second part, a practical workaround here would be to just take a reasonable sub sample of your 1.37 GB data set.  Do you really need to build your model using *all* the data points in the original data set?  Or, would say a 10% sub sample also give you a statistically significant model?  If you lower the size of the data set, then you solve the memory problem with R.

Keep in mind here that R runs completely in-memory, meaning that once you have exceeded available memory, you may be out of luck.

Comment: First part: exactly.
Second part: I want to use all my data, because I want to make a complex model. And I need to know how confident I am in my estimates, so I need to use all my data. Hence my question.

Comment: @HeyJane I'm not sure you need to use all your data.  To test this, you could take say a 10% subsample of your data and compare descriptive stats of that subset to the original dataset.

Comment: Yes, I need to use all my data to assess how sure I am of my estimates. And also, I want a very complex model. And with all due respect, you are not adressing my problem. You are just saying "reduce the data"

Comment: You may not be able to run `glm` in R on this size dataset given your memory constraints.  And no, in my experience you don't always need to use such a large dataset.  The complexity of the model has little to do with this argument.